# How to show properties of a custom control in the Visual Studio IDE 2008 properties window?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have created a custom graph control in WPF. Now I want to show it's properties in the properties window of the Visual Studio 2008 IDE so a user can change the properties at design time. How can I do this with WPF custom controls?
Please help.

Rangana.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything: Visual Studio will work it out by inspecting the control's API.

However, you can ship a .design.dll assembly to customise or improve the experience.  See [WPF Designer Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628660.aspx) in the Visual Studio help, or [Jim Nakashima's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2007/08/10/adding-design-time-metadata-to-cider-and-blend.aspx) for a more tutorial walkthrough.  But to reiterate this additional metadata is *optional* and your users will be able to configure most basic properties without it.